# Using actionLib to create a turtlesim motion sequence

Tags: actionlib, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to send a sequence of motions to turtlesim.  My larger program does a lot of processing before arriving at an angle1-distanceForward-angle2 command sequence.  Sending messages to turtlesim does not work.  After messages are published, processing begins again and the messages may be squashed by the next command sequence.

So, I'm trying to create a actionlib server/client to wait for the sequence to complete before resuming my other processing.

1. Is this a valid way to go about this and
2. Looking at turtle_actionlib, where is the file ShapeAction.h?

Thanks,
Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12656/using-actionlib-to-create-a-turtlesim-motion-sequence/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. yes, it is. Actionlib is intended for such things that take time and you want to wait for/observe.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1